# Global variable memset vs local variable creation again and again

Tags: c

In a code I need to read a file consisting a million lines of data and each line of data is to be broken into small pieces & then store those pieces into DB.

Now some function `X` is reading file line after line & passing each line  to the function Y which breaks the feed into chunks of data (marked by byte position), storing theme into local variables & then store it into DB with the help of those local (host) variables.

At this moment on every call of function `Y` I am creating local variables (variables are local to function `Y`) again and again - once for every call by function `X` rather than just declaring these variables global & `memset`ing them on each call.

The program runs fine as it processes all the records without any issue & processes millions of records but I am not sure if my strategy of creating local variables again and again is right - can you please suggest if `memset` is the option I should have gone with.

OR am I moving towards over-engineering by putting my mind to this dilemma?

Comment: "The program runs fine" means you don't have a problem. Why are you fussing over something that works?

Comment: A 'local variable' is not interesting. How it gets the value assigned might be. Also, why not just use pointers? And presumably there is a need to `memset` - what is it? A little example might go a long way ..

Comment: @tadman I was thinking if one is better than the other - just for learning & maybe speeding it a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring local variables takes zero instructions since they go in the stack. If this was C++ and ctors/dtors were a consideration, it could be a different story.

Perhaps you are worried about the memory copies. If your program is compiled with optimizations, perhaps even with link-time ones, then the optimizer can see through the function definition and may even remove the variables if the original ones can be reused in place.

> OR am I moving towards over-engineering by putting my mind to this dilemma?

If you are worried, you should profile both options!

Answer (score 1):

Local variables don't really cost anything to create, they're just positions on the stack where stuff happens. Allocations can be expensive if you're doing a lot of them, but if it's just a few that happen to be large it's inconsequential in terms of overall performance.

In general global variables are something you want to strictly avoid. They just complicate your code in subtle, difficult to fix ways. If your instinct was to switch to globals you really need to think that through and figure out why.

I have a feeling this is unfounded speculation and paranoia about the cost of allocations. Do some measurements to determine what the cost is, don't just guess. Computers are far faster than you can possibly imagine. What you perceive as difficult can often be effortless to them.